# Efficient float to int without overflow

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point

```
using int_type = int;
int_type min = std::numeric_limits<Depth>::min();
int_type max = std::numeric_limits<Depth>::max();

int_type convert(float f) {
    if(f < static_cast<float>(min)) return min; // overflow
    else if(f > static_cast<float>(max)) return max; // overflow
    else return static_cast<int_type>(f);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to convert `float f` to `int_type`, while clamping it to the minimal and maximal values of the integer type?
For example, without casting `min` and `max` to `float` for the comparisons.

Comment: How much of your time is spent in this function?  I am surprised if it is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Sometimes</strike> Almost always, trusting the compiler is the best thing to do.

This code:

```
template<class Integral>
__attribute__((noinline))
int convert(float f)
{
    using int_type = Integral;
    constexpr int_type min = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::min();
    constexpr int_type max = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::max();

    constexpr float fmin = static_cast<float>(min);
    constexpr float fmax = static_cast<float>(max);

    if(f < fmin) return min; // overflow
    if(f > fmax) return max; // overflow
    return static_cast<int_type>(f);
}
```

compiled with -O2 and -fomit-frame-pointer, yields:

```
__Z7convertIiEif:                       ## @_Z7convertIiEif
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $-2147483648, %eax      ## imm = 0xFFFFFFFF80000000
    movss   LCPI1_0(%rip), %xmm1    ## xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    ucomiss %xmm0, %xmm1
    ja  LBB1_3
    movl    $2147483647, %eax       ## imm = 0x7FFFFFFF
    ucomiss LCPI1_1(%rip), %xmm0
    ja  LBB1_3
    cvttss2si   %xmm0, %eax
LBB1_3:
    retq
```

I'm not sure it could be any more efficient.

Note LCPI_x defined here:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__literal4,4byte_literals
    .align  2
LCPI1_0:
    .long   3472883712              ## float -2.14748365E+9
LCPI1_1:
    .long   1325400064              ## float 2.14748365E+9
```

> How about clamping using fmin(), fmax()... [thanks to njuffa for the question]

The code does become more efficient, because the conditional jumps are removed. However, it starts to behave incorrectly at the clamping limits.

Consider:

```
template<class Integral>
__attribute__((noinline))
int convert2(float f)
{
    using int_type = Integral;
    constexpr int_type min = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::min();
    constexpr int_type max = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::max();

    constexpr float fmin = static_cast<float>(min);
    constexpr float fmax = static_cast<float>(max);

    f = std::min(f, fmax);
    f = std::max(f, fmin);
    return static_cast<int_type>(f);
}
```

call with

```
auto i = convert2<int>(float(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()));
```

results in:

```
-2147483648
```

Clearly we need to reduce the limits by epsilon because of a float's inability to accurately represent the full range of an int, so...

```
template<class Integral>
__attribute__((noinline))
int convert2(float f)
{
    using int_type = Integral;
    constexpr int_type min = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::min();
    constexpr int_type max = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::max();

    constexpr float fmin = static_cast<float>(min) - (std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() * static_cast<float>(min));
    constexpr float fmax = static_cast<float>(max) - (std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() * static_cast<float>(max));

    f = std::min(f, fmax);
    f = std::max(f, fmin);
    return static_cast<int_type>(f);
}
```

Should be better...

except that now the same function call yields:

```
2147483392
```

Incidentally, working on this actually led me to a bug in the original code. Because of the same rounding error issue, the `>` and `<` operators need to be replaced with `>=` and `<=`.

like so:

```
template<class Integral>
__attribute__((noinline))
int convert(float f)
{
    using int_type = Integral;
    constexpr int_type min = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::min();
    constexpr int_type max = std::numeric_limits<int_type>::max();

    constexpr float fmin = static_cast<float>(min);
    constexpr float fmax = static_cast<float>(max);

    if(f <= fmin) return min; // overflow
    if(f >= fmax) return max; // overflow
    return static_cast<int_type>(f);
}
```

Comment: How about clamping using `fmin()`, `fmax()` prior to the conversion to integer? Wouldn't that result in even shorter code? If I recall correctly, there are hardware instructions for floating-point min/max.

Comment: @njuffa tried it. the results are interesting! see updated answer.

Comment: I see where I went wrong in my thinking. For clamping to work correctly in floating-point space, the integer limits must be exactly representable as a floating-point number. Clearly, 32-bit integer limits are not representable in a `float`, but they are representable in a `double`. So I think this can be made to work for `int_type` with fewer than 53 bits, but would require additional conversions, negating any potential performance benefit.

Comment: @njuffa I wouldn't say that you went wrong in your thinking. I think the epsilon solution is actually optimal. Let's face it, when the numbers become that high the float is inaccurate anyway, so what does it matter if the clamp is a few hundred below int_max?

Comment: I don't suppose it is terribly important but perhaps it might be worth negating one of the clamping conditions in order to trap NaNs.

Comment: The 32-bit `int` was an example, didn't realize that `float` cant represent `INT_MAX`. The actual program uses 8 or 16 bit unsigned integers, and maps `float` or `double` values in [-1, +1] to the full range of the integer. It should be efficient because it does this for each pixel in a sequence of image frames.

Comment: @tmlen in which case the second method, using min/max is a teeny bit faster if done in a tight loop. However, you will want to write tests to check the edge cases (float(max_value)+-epsilon and float(min) +-epsilon)

Answer (score 1):

For 32-bit integers, you can let the CPU do some of the clamping work for you.

The `cvtss2si` instruction will actually return 0x80000000 in the case of an out of range floating point number. This lets you eliminate one test most of the time:

```
int convert(float value)
{
    int result = _mm_cvtss_si32(_mm_load_ss(&value));
    if (result == 0x80000000 && value > 0.0f)
        result = 0x7fffffff;
    return result;
}
```

If you have lots of them to convert, then [_mm_cvtps_epi32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdc42k5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) lets you process four at once (with the same behaviour on overflow). That should be much faster than processing them one at a time, but you'd need to structure the code differently to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to truncate, you can take advantage of avx2 and avx instructions 512:

```
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    __m256 a = {5.423423, -4.243423, 423.4234234, FLT_MAX, 79.4234876, 19.7, 8.5454, 7675675.6};
    __m256i b = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(a);
    void p256_hex_u32(__m256i in) {
    alignas(32) uint32_t v[8];
    _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)v, in);
    printf("v4_u32: %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5], v[6], v[7]);
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -mavx2  a.cpp && ./a.out
```

and for mavx512 (my cpu does not support so I will not provide a working test, feel free to edit):

```
_mm512_maskz_cvtt_roundpd_epi64(k, value, _MM_FROUND_NO_EXC);
```